# Is there a wireless alternative to using the HDMI cable to connect a monitor

Tags: pi-3, wifi, hdmi, display

Is there any way to connect a Raspberry Pi 3 wirelessly to a monitor?
I am building a (caterpillar)tracked robot and want to develop code and test stuff out without needing the HDMI cable to be plugged in.

Comment: That always depends on your monitor. Which wireless connection capabilities does it have?

Comment: You can also use remote dektop. Or develop on an acutal PC and just use Putty

Comment: I highly recommend not to use Putty but either Microsofts latest own implementation of SSH or by installing the Windows Subsystem for Linux. It is also better to use a *nix system anyway.

Comment: If you need to see what's actually on the not connected screen, you could use VNC. That also involves a separate computer.

Comment: @kwasmich I'm not aware of my monitor having any wireless connection capabilities and I assumed it had none, so was expecting suggestions involving dongles or some other pieces of hardware. FYI my monitor is this: http://www.lg.com/uk/monitors/lg-34UM88

Comment: @Christian cool, had not even considered using remote desktop, cool suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to control the pi wirelessly, the easy answer, if you can work a command-line, is to enable the pi for wifi (newer versions using the 'stretch' image require a blank 'ssh' file under /boot). Then you can ssh to the pi from another machine, mac or win, using 'ssh pi@ip_address'. 
If what you really want is to have your robot 'see' and throw the image it sees as it's driving around, I recommend getting a PiCamera (around $30) which hooks up to the board. Then check out this blog to live-stream the video from the camera: https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/blogs/streaming-live-to-youtube-and-facebook-using-raspberry-pi-camera/969a7932d47d42a79ba72c81da4d9b66

Answer (score 0):

I would look down the avenue of screencasting. It would likely mean that you'd need to initially set it up on the Pi with traditional HDMI temporarily. [The following thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=157734) discusses some areas to look into. But I'm sure there is some Google Chromecast set up you put together.